# Access the value of the array from the text in Watson

Tags: watson-conversation

I have list of values defined in the values of array inside the text element.
Now, when the value of the aray is "Counting finished" I would like to route the flow to new node and pass some text[image] to the user. How to achive the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that is output text the conversation tree can't see it unless you put it into the input or a context variable, and send it back into the tree.

The easier option is to create a counter. There is more details and an example conversation file here:

https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/22/using-counters-in-conversation/

**Summary:**

You create a context variable like `countdown` for example, and set it with a value to countdown from.

Then in your input text you can add the following code to initiate a decrement.

```
<? context.countdown-- ?>
```

This will be outputted though, so you can use a `continue from` to jump to another node which has `append` set to false. This will erase the counter from being displayed.

Optionally you can set the context variable directly like as follows.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "Decrementing countdown counter"
  },
  "context": {
    "countdown": "<? context.countdown-- ?>"
  }
}
```

This had issues in earlier versions of conversation though. I believe it should work now without issue.

Comment: Thanks Simon. One more question. How did you create a condition "Continue from User Input" in your blog . I am able to create condition but without userInput.

Comment: When you select continue from, click on the little speech bubble that sits between the two nodes.